# C++ Custom memory management using brk() system call to allocate memory?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I wrote a basic custom memory management allocator which would grab a chunk of memory, pre-create X objects so that whenever I needed to "create" an object I could grab one of the pre-created ones and simply assign data members (memory was already allocated).

I used `placement-new`:

```
//Grab a chunk of memory
char* buf = new char [sizeof(X) * num_objs]; 

//Pre-create a lot of objects
for(std::int64_t i=0; i<num_objs; i++){
    char* c = buf + (sizeof(X) * i);

    //This line creates the Order object at location c
    X* x = new(c)X;
}

//Assign data members to objects
for(std::int64_t i=0; i<num_objs; i++){
    char* buf_loc = buf + (sizeof(X) * i); 
    X* my_x = reinterpret_cast <X*> (buf_loc);
    my_x->a = 1;
    my_x->b = 2;
    my_x->c = 3;
    my_x->d = 4;
}
```

How easy/practical would it be to change the above and directly grab memory from the OS using `brk()`?

Comment: If you are going to mess around with `brk` yourself, then very likely the libstdc++ / libc will not work properly (they rely on a working `malloc`). Are you fine with it?

Comment: Instead of using `brk`, use `mmap()` on `/dev/zero` to get a block of memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507945/mmap-with-dev-zero

Comment: @Barmar I had a look at mmap() vs brk() and it seems the difference is that mmap() can allocate at various positions (brk cannot) but is slower than brk()?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal I dont understand what you mean by it will "mess around" by it? What do you mean by this/why would it interfere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `brk` will probably interfere with the regular C/C++ memory allocator. Even if you don't use regular `new` or `malloc()` in your code, it might be used in libraries.

If you want to manage your own memory, use `mmap()` on `/dev/zero` to get an empty block of memory.  I think you can do this repeatedly to get new blocks.

Comment: What do you mean by interference with the regular C/C++ memory allocator? Im not doubting it- just wanting to learn what you mean/what is happening.

Comment: `malloc` probably assumes that it's the only code that's calling `brk`, so everything in there is its own heap.

Comment: Oh I get you- so it wouldnt be a problem if I had no other heap-allocated memory but if I allocated other objects on the heap via malloc/new I could have issues?

Comment: Right. And like we said, if you call any library functions, they might allocate on the heap.

Comment: e.g. Boost library etc