# mmapping /dev/zero on Mac OSX gives invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, macos, mmap

So I am trying to port some code from Linux to Mac OSX. During porting I came across this code.

```
static void allocZeroMap(unsigned long size, int prot, const char *name)
{
    struct map *newnode;
    int fd;
    char buf[11];

    fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("couldn't open /dev/zero\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newnode = zmalloc(sizeof(struct map));
    newnode->name = strdup(name);
    newnode->size = size;
    newnode->prot = prot;
    newnode->type = INITIAL_MAP;
    newnode->ptr = mmap(NULL, size, prot, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (newnode->ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newnode->name = zmalloc(80);

    sprintf(newnode->name, "anon(%s)", name);

    num_initial_mappings++;

    list_add_tail(&newnode->list, &initial_mappings->list);

    sizeUnit(size, buf);
    printf("mapping[%d]: (zeropage %s) %p (%s)\n",
           num_initial_mappings - 1, name, newnode->ptr, buf);

    close(fd);
}
```

So I figured that I would need to just switch `newnode->ptr = mmap(NULL, size, prot, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);` to `newnode->ptr = mmap(NULL, size, prot, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);` because Mac OSX does not have the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag and uses `MAP_ANON` instead.

But when I run the program, that mmap call fails with Invalid argument. So my next thought was check the man page for what causes Invalid arguments errors. The first cause is that `MAP_FIXED` is set and the addr argument is not page aligned, but I'm not calling `MAP_FIXED`. Second it's says it will return Invalid argument if you don't specify either `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED` but I'm using `MAP_SHARED` so that shouldn't be it. Next it says the len argument must not be negative, so I printed the size variable and ran it and it's a positive value. The final reason is that the offset argument is not page aligned, but I am passing zero so that shouldn't be the problem either.

So next I checked stack overflow and saw this question [mmap with /dev/zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507945/mmap-with-dev-zero) . I tried using `MAP_FILE` instead of `MAP_ANON` but now I get Operation not supported by device, which the man page says means I am missing `MAP_ANON`. So I tried adding `MAP_ANON` so that I have `mmap(NULL, size, prot, MAP_FILE | MAP_ANON| MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);` but that returns Invalid argument as well.

So how do I mmap /dev/zero on Mac OSX or at least create a zero-filled memory map on Mac OSX?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) has an example with the comment _Does not work on OS X, as you can't mmap over /dev/zero_

Comment: If that ends up being the case I will open a bug report with apple, but whats another use case of /dev/zero on Mac OSX if you can't mmap it?

Comment: You can use `cat /dev/zero` to get an endless stream of (empty) data.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass -1 instead of `fd` as the value of the file descriptor as per `mmap()` man page. Also as you said `MAP_ANON` is the correct option for MacOS (at least older versions) and there is not need for `MAP_FILE`.